# Removing default values while using xmlserializer

Tags: c#-4.0

I have to remove datamember with default values in C#.

structure of classes are `[DataContract]`

```
public class class1
{
    [DataMember]
    public string A1;

    [DataMember]
    public int A2;

    [DataMember]
    public class2 class2Instance;
}

[DataContract]
public class class2
{
    [DataMember]
    public string B1;

    [DataMember]
    public int B2;     
}
```

I am serializing class1 by using `xmlserializer`.

I don't want to serialize properties having default values. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ShouldSerialize` methods.

Just add member name at the end of the method name (`ShouldSerializeA1` for `A1`), and `XmlSerializer` will call it in order to know if it should be serializable. Add your logic in it (default in your case)

```
public class class1
{
    [DataMember]
    public string A1;

    [DataMember]
    public int A2;

    [DataMember]
    public class2 class2Instance;

    public Boolean ShouldSerializeA1()
    {
        return this.A1 != String.Empty;
    }

    public Boolean ShouldSerializeA2()
    {
        return this.A2 != 0;
    }

    public Boolean ShouldSerializeclass2Instance()
    {
        return this.class2Instance != null;
    }
}
```